# Pandas picks wrong columns with df[[]]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large csv file, 40+ columns, I'm trying to sort it using `pandas` and only write selected ones into a  new file. Here's my code:

Edit: I was probably wrong to assume I've done everything correctly up until the end, here's the entire file: I read in 10 csv files, add them to one, filter the rows so that they are unique in a way I need them to, then I want to filter again, this time select just the few columns. 
I am completely new to python, so the code probably looks disgusting and there's the issue I assume.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = ['airOT199701.csv', 'airOT199702.csv', 'airOT199703.csv', 'airOT199704.csv', 'airOT199705.csv', 'airOT199706.csv', 'airOT199707.csv', 'airOT199708.csv', 'airOT199709.csv', 'airOT199710.csv', 'airOT199711.csv', 'airOT199712.csv']
    with open('filterflights.csv', 'w') as outcsv:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, fieldnames = ["YEAR","MONTH","DAY_OF_MONTH","DAY_OF_WEEK","FL_DATE","UNIQUE_CARRIER","TAIL_NUM","FL_NUM","ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID","ORIGIN","ORIGIN_STATE_ABR","DEST_AIRPORT_ID","DEST","DEST_STATE_ABR","CRS_DEP_TIME","DEP_TIME","DEP_DELAY","DEP_DELAY_NEW","DEP_DEL15","DEP_DELAY_GROUP","TAXI_OUT","WHEELS_OFF","WHEELS_ON","TAXI_IN","CRS_ARR_TIME","ARR_TIME","ARR_DELAY","ARR_DELAY_NEW","ARR_DEL15","ARR_DELAY_GROUP","CANCELLED","CANCELLATION_CODE","DIVERTED","CRS_ELAPSED_TIME","ACTUAL_ELAPSED_TIME","AIR_TIME","FLIGHTS","DISTANCE","DISTANCE_GROUP","CARRIER_DELAY","WEATHER_DELAY","NAS_DELAY","SECURITY_DELAY","LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY","DIFFERENCE"])
        writer.writeheader()
        filewriter = csv.writer(outcsv, delimiter=',')
        for i in range(len(files)):
            reader = csv.reader(open(files[i], 'r'), delimiter=',')
            next(reader, None)
            result = set()
            for r in reader:
                r.append(abs(int(r[8])-int(r[11]))%25)
                key = (r[7],r[8],r[11])
                if key not in result:
                    filewriter.writerow(r)
                    result.add(key)
    df = pd.read_csv('filterflights.csv')
    df.header(3)
    df = df[["FL_DATE","FL_NUM","ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID","ORIGIN","ORIGIN_STATE_ABR", "DEST_AIRPORT_ID","DEST","DEST_STATE_ABR", "DEP_TIME", "ARR_TIME", "DISTANCE", "DIFFERENCE"]]
    df.header(3)
    df.to_csv('filteredflights.csv', index=False)
```

I get the error:AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'header' in line 23. All csv files are in the same folder as the python file

Possible issue: original csv files do not have `DIFFERENCE` column, can that cause the issue? Trying to append value with r.append, but maybe it doesn't know what to append to?

Comment: Check the input file's header.

Comment: display few rows of your filterflights.csv file.

Comment: Please show header including first data (from `df.header(3)`) before and after the `df = df[[...]]`

Comment: I reworked the question because I ran into the "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'header'" error, which probably mean I messed up way before

Comment: I'm not quiet sure what you are doing to drop the duplicates so I can't write a script as an answer, but I'm pretty sure you will you'll be much better off if you would read all your `files` with `pd.read_csv()`, use `pd.concat()` or `df.append()` to concat them, and then use `df.drop_duplicates()` to drop the duplicates as you want. Currently I think you have something wrong with writing the temporary file, which causes this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`pandas.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to subset the data frame and preserve given order,

```
col_subset = ["FL_DATE","FL_NUM","ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID","ORIGIN","ORIGIN_STATE_ABR", "DEST_AIRPORT_ID","DEST","DEST_STATE_ABR", "DEP_TIME", "ARR_TIME", "DISTANCE", "DIFFERENCE"]
df = df.reindex(columns= col_subset)
```